# Vue 3 with Naive UI, can't get Modal to work correctly

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I am having an issue with a vue app..  previous dev's used lang="ts" and not the standard vue export default so I am stuck using it this way.

I am trying to use the Naive UI Modal component, I setup my button to trigger the modal but can't get it to work..  It should open a modal with close buttons but tried various things and no go..

Can someone take a look and see what I am missing?

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-chihiro-hy11zp

Answer (score 0):

I think your import path of your modal was wrong.

You can use modal like this:

```html
<template>
  <n-button @click="showModal = true">
    Start Me up
  </n-button>
  <n-modal v-model:show="showModal">
    <n-card
      style="width: 600px"
      title="Modal"
      :bordered="false"
      size="huge"
      role="dialog"
      aria-modal="true"
    >
      <template #header-extra>
        Oops!
      </template>
      Content
      <template #footer>
        Footer
      </template>
    </n-card>
  </n-modal>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    return {
      showModal: ref(false)
    }
  }
})
</script>
```